# How to reconstruct a name with a split String in Java?

Tags: java, string, error-handling, split

First some info about my project,
I'm following a tutorial task where the main goal is to learn to work with error handling,
but I'm not at that part quite yet, I am working with establishing the main classes.
Thats what I need a little help and guidance with,(but errors are supposed to come up and be detected
so that I can learn to fix them later, but that's not the main question here, just information.)
Here's 3 of the classes which I've completed.
Student with two private fields: Name name and CourseCollection course.
Name with two fields String firstName and String surname.
CourseCollection with ArrayList  courses.

(Info: Later, I will work with class UserDatabase to collect and load a collection of students,
+ class DatavaseFormatException which will represent errors, but I think it would be easier to finish those 3 classes above first? Correct me if 
I'm wrong.)

QUESTION:I need a little help with class Name, I don't think my work is correct.
My main issue is with the method String encode, and constructor Name(String encodedIdentity)
where I want to return the names, split by a ;. Here's what I have

```
enter code here
public class Name
//instanciating the persons first and last name as Strings.
private String firstName;
private String surname;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Name- setting the text values for a name
 */ 
public Name(String firstName, String surname)
{
firstName = this.firstName;
surname = this.surname;
}


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Name- reconstructing the fields
 * from a coded name
 */
public Name(String encodedIdentity)
{
//Here, the name is supposed to be coded as a text value, with the first
//and last names split with a ;
this.encodedIdentity=encodedIdentity;
//I am getting my first error here
}
```

//getters for firstname and surname here

```
/**
 * This method will return the name, with the first and last name split
 * by a ;
 */
public String encode()
{
    //Could I use a split String here? If so how?
    return firstName + ";" + surname;
}
```

}

I can guarantee I will need further help with my work. Thanks in advance, I find
people on StackOverflow to be very helpful as I don't have anyone (other than my books)
to ask for help. (I know you guys are not free teachers. But if anyone would voulenteer to help me outside of this I would highly appreciate it.
(Sorry if that's not allowed to ask for!))

EDIT: Thanks to you guys, my class is now compiling. I am not sure how to test it yet, but this is what I have now. Does it look correct?

```
 public class Name
```

{

```
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Name- setting the text values for a name
 */ 
public Name(String firstName, String surname)
{
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.surname = surname;
```

}

```
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Name- reconstructing the fields
 * from a coded name
 */
public Name(String encodedIdentity)
{
String names = firstName + surname;
String[] fullname = names.split( "\\;");
if(fullname.length != 2 )
{
System.out.println(fullname);
}
}


/**
 * Getting the firstname of the person
 * @return firstName
 */
public String getFirstName() 
{
    return firstName;
}

/**
 * Getting the surname of the person
 * @return surname
 */
public String getSurname()
{
    return surname;
}

/**
 * This method will return the name, with the first and last name split
 * by a ;
 */
public String encode()
{
String encode = (firstName + ";" + surname);
return encode;
}

}
```

Comment: There is no field encodedIdentity. So the code doesn't make sense. As you said yourself, you need to split the given encodedIdentity argument, and store the two parts you get after splitting it into firstName ans surName. So do just that. You also need to fix basic syntax errors (like `public class Name {` that needs a curly brace), and to indent your code properly, so that you understand its structure.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. But how can I write the code (split string) successfully for this purpose?

Comment: Read the javadoc of String. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are given an "encoded id", split it to get the names:

```
public Name(String encodedIdentity){
    String[] names = split( ";", encodedIdentity );
    if( names.length != 2 ) throw new IllegalArgumentError("...");
    firstName = names[0];
    surname = names[1];
}
```

One does not store all the variants with which an object's attributes may be specified. Therefore, there shouldn't be a field encodedIdentity.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful! Do you have any idea how I could proceed with the "public String encode" method? It is supposed to return the firstname + surname separated with ; - could I just use a         public String encode()
    {
        //Could I use a split String here? If so how?
    String encode = (firstName + ";" + surname);
    return encode;
    }

Comment: Your `String encode()` is fine as you posted it. Didn't you try it?

Comment: It wouldn't compile. I posted the improved version of my code as an edit above, it compiles now but I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: There was no problem in this method; it was elsewhere. Why don't you try it to see whether it is correct?

Comment: The current version is not correct. You have ignored my recommendation for the constructor `Name(String encodedIdentity)` -- why?

Answer (score 0):

First correct your name constructor with two fields
replace this

```
public Name(String firstName, String surname)
{
 firstName = this.firstName;
 surname = this.surname;
}
```

with

```
public Name(String firstName, String surname)
{
 this.firstName = firstName;
 this.surname = surname;
}
```

Also, can you paste the error from console here. so that it will be easier to find the exact problem.